# Is it possible to build only one given image with quarkus-container-image-docker?

Tags: quarkus

By default the quarkus-container-image-docker dependency builds the jvm and native docker images.
Is it possible to build only one given image?

Comment: You can remove (or comment) the part you don't want to build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
If I well understand the docker image quarkus maven build process, the dependency io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-docker builds the images for the 2 dockerfiles Dockerfile.native and Dockerfile.jvm.
Only the native one interests us. The jvm image is generated through a legacy process we don't want to change.